# How to extract a url from a string with spaces and punctuation marks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

Let's say you have a string like this:
`"This is my.linkhttps://google.com/1two3!!!"`

And you want to get exactly:
`https://google.com/1two3`

Tried:

```
message.split.select{ |m| m.include?("google") }
```

but it does not split periods. so ti includes `my.link` and `!!!`.

```
message.split(/[\s.]+/)
```

but it splits the link itself.

Comment: Is using regex an option? Depending on how varied the urls you want to find are: https:\/\/\w+.\w+\/\w+ https://regex101.com/r/bmKCmH/1

Comment: What is the source of the string? Is there some point earlier in the process at which the text is more structured? For example, is this string coming from a Nokogiri node? `node.inner_text` If so, there is probably a better solution to the problem than a regex.

Comment: According to RFC 1738, an exclamation mark is a valid character in a URL. What is the rule behind you not considering the `!!!` as part of the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex that accommodates any url:

```rb
"This is my.linkhttps://google.com/1two3!!!".match(/https:[\/\w\.]*/)[0]
#=> "https://google.com/1two3"
```

Comment: If `str` holds your string `str[/https:[\/\w\.]*/]` is a little simpler.